# How to get value from HTML form in Meteor Event when the form is dynamically created?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

```
Template.dpVar.events = {
        'click .addproduct' : function  (err) {
            console.log("testing");
            console.log(result);
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var Temp_Name = result[i];
               This is the problem //var Temp_Val = document.getElementById(Temp_Name).value
                console.log("temp name is ", Temp_Name);

               productDB.insert({ Temp_Name:Temp_Val });
               console.log("temp val is ", Temp_Val);
            }

        }
}
```

HTML

```
<template name="dpVar">
  <h1>variants</h1> 

  <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
    <tbody>
    {{#each variant}}
      {{#each VARIENTS}}
        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "Text"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id={{this.NAME}}>
             </td> 

          </tr>
        {{/if}}

        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "price"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td><input type="text" id={{this.NAME}}></td> 
          </tr>
        {{/if}}

        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "color"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td>
            <div>
              <select>
                <option>Color</option>
                <option>Green</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>Red</option>
                <option>Blue</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </td> 
          </tr>
        {{/if}}

        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "boolean"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td><input type="radio" id={{this.NAME}}></td> 
          </tr>
        {{/if}}

        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "checkbox"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id={{this.NAME}}></td> 
              </tr>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "string"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td><input type="text" id={{this.NAME}}></td> 
          </tr>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "date"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td><input data-provide="datepicker" type="text" id={{this.NAME}}></td> 
          </tr>
        {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button class="btn btn-success addproduct" id="CreateNewProduct">Create new product</button>   
</template>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a form with a submit button? Using the onSubmit event you would have access to `this` (the form) and juggle with its inputs.

Comment: can you explain, I tried the form method also given in answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the `result` variable in your click event? If I understand it correctly, the `result` variable is a list of form elements?

The correct way how to handle forms in Meteor is via submit form event. Also, do not define variable names as `Temp_Name` or `Temp_Val`, it's against conventions. Name your variables according to conventions: `tempName` and `tempVal`. Conventions are important! Read more about conventions: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp

I see that you use parameter with name `err` in your click event. You can name the parameter as you want, but `err` is confusing. It should be named `event` or `evt` because it's actually an event object, not error object.

So the correct code is:

```
Template.dpVar.events = {
    'submit .add-product-form' : function  (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault(); //prevent form to change URL
        var form = evt.target; //this is the .add-product-form element
        console.log("testing", form);
        console.log(result);
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var tempName = result[i];
            var tempVal = form[tempName].value;
            console.log("temp name is ", tempName);

            productDB.insert({ tempName: tempVal });
            console.log("temp val is ", tempVal);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I can see you use forEach to find and insert dynamic value into DB. I don't know why you do it this way, but `form[tempName]` can be undefined when input with name of value `tempName` is not present in HTML. You should check if `form[tempName]` is not undefined before accessing its property `value`:

```
Template.dpVar.events = {
    'submit .add-product-form' : function  (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault(); //prevent form to change URL
        var form = evt.target; //this is the .add-product-form element
        console.log("testing", form);
        console.log(result);
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var tempName = result[i];
            if (form[tempName] !== void 0) {
                var tempVal = form[tempName].value;
                console.log("temp name is ", tempName);

                productDB.insert({ tempName: tempVal });
                console.log("temp val is ", tempVal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now add form in your HTML, use `name` attributes for inputs instead of `IDs`, so we can access form inputs via their names in JavaScript (`evt.target[inputName].value`)

Also, provide values for your option items of the select element. Here is your new HTML:

```
<template name="dpVar">
  <h1>variants</h1>

  <!-- here is our form -->
  <form class="add-product-form">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
      <tbody>
      {{#each variant}}
        {{#each VARIENTS}}
          {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "Text"}}
            <tr>
              <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name={{this.NAME}}>
               </td>

            </tr>
          {{/if}}

          {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "price"}}
            <tr>
              <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
              <td><input type="text" name={{this.NAME}}></td>
            </tr>
          {{/if}}

          {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "color"}}
            <tr>
              <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
              <td>
              <div>
                <select name={{this.NAME}}>
                  <option>Color</option>
                  <option value="Green">Green</option>
                  <option value="White">White</option>
                  <option value="Red">Red</option>
                  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          {{/if}}

          {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "boolean"}}
            <tr>
              <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
              <td><input type="radio" name={{this.NAME}}></td>
            </tr>
          {{/if}}

          {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "checkbox"}}
            <tr>
              <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name={{this.NAME}}></td>
                </tr>
          {{/if}}
          {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "string"}}
            <tr>
              <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
              <td><input type="text" name={{this.NAME}}></td>
            </tr>
          {{/if}}
          {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "date"}}
            <tr>
              <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
              <td><input data-provide="datepicker" type="text" name={{this.NAME}}></td>
            </tr>
          {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
      {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- here I added type="submit" for button, so it submits the form -->
    <button class="btn btn-success addproduct" id="CreateNewProduct" type="submit">Create new product</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:

Comment: this message is coming

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot one line of code in event: `evt.preventDefault(); //prevent form to change URL` I have updated the answer. You can read about MIME type here: http://www.codeitive.com/0ymVXjqXgX/meteor-resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-texthtml.html

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: var tempVal = form[tempName].value on this line

Comment: It means that form input with name `tempName` does not exist. Use console.log for investigating the issue.  `console.log(tempName);` and `console.log(form[tempName]);` to see which input does not exist.

Comment: console.log(form[tempName]) is undefined

Comment: Are you sure `tempName` is a name of input in your HTML? `<input name="..." />`

Comment: <td><input type="radio" name={{this.NAME}}></td>

Comment: I am creating a dynamic form so this will be used multiple times whenever the datatype is text, this will print

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78790/discussion-between-tomas-hromnik-and-garima).

Answer (score 1):

Well if you don't know the current value of the current DOM Element, you should do find by nodes, something like this.

```
  Template.dpVar.events = {
            'click .addproduct' : function  (event,template) {
                var instance = Template.instance(),
                    findFromParent =  instance.$(event.target).find('dynamicSelector').val();
                    console.log("temp val is " + parent);
            }
    }
```

You got the idea, just find the dom element by the actual event (in this case the `<form>`) and lester do a [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) by whatever class or id the dynamic content have, if the DOM element dosnt have `id or class`, use data attribute or `childNodes`